# Unable to register my Lumia 1020 as a testing phone for windows phone apps

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a Nokia Lumia 1020 that I need to register as a testing device for my Windows Phone Apps. It is running Lumia Cyan thus Windows 8.1. I have Windows Phone SDK 8.1 and 8.0 installed on my machine and when I try to use the Windows Phone Developer Registration (8.1) interface or the normal one (Windows Phone Developer Registration unde Windows Phone SDK 8.0 i keep getting the same error. `Unable to connect to a Phone. Make sure that the Windows Phone IP over USB Transport Service is running`. I try to restart the service, switch ports, switch from Wi-Fi to 3G network on my phone. Nothing works. I have ensured that the Phone is showing as a device under File Explorer and when I connect the phone to my computer it does launch the Windows Phone app for desktop well. I am not sure what to do at this point and it's getting frustrating. I have tried to reinstall the SDKs and still nothing. I do have a developer account and developer account details intact. Please help... someone.... anyone :(

Comment: Maybe try to restart your phone? Sometimes works...

Comment: Aha... found the solution....Let me post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. I went to device manager and found under Universal Serial Bus Devices and found device drivers of my phone on all the ports where I had connected the USB cable. I then right-clicked on one that showed that needed an update. I clicked on update device driver software where it scanned for updates and found out that the driver was up to date then I realized that it was not enabled. I enabled it and it was able to recognize the phone. However I had to keep restarting the service since the software kept going offline as well as switching from 3G to Wi-Fi. And it finally worked :)